# htaccess redirect all images to new domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have moved my website to a new domain and put the following htaccess 301 redirect rule in place which is working fine for all URLs.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domianname.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The problem is I can still access images, css, javascript files on the old domain. I have looked around everywhere and tried various things but I am unable to get this to work where I can also redirect all image files, css files, javascript files from the old domain to the new domain.

Comment: So you've got 2 rules: the first says "Redirect **everything** to domainname.com", and the second says "Redirect **everything** to subdomain1.domainname.com", so which is it?

Comment: Sorry its the first domain, i have removed the sub domain from the code.

Comment: `i can still access images, css, javascript files on the old domain` might be a silly question - sure they're not cached somewhere? Do you have any other .htaccess files in those directories?

Comment: Hi, the images are not cached and i only have the one htaccess file stored in the root of the website. Thanks